# In Python unittest, how can I call a function after all tests in a TestCase have been executed?

Tags: python, python-unittest

Im running some unittests in Python and would like to call a function after all of the test cases have been run.

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.credentials = credentials

    def tearDown(self):
        print("finished running " + self._testMethodName)

    def tearDownModule(self):
        print("finished running all tests")

    def test_1(self):
        #do something

    def test_2(self):
        #do something else
```

setUp and tearDown are running before and after each individual test. Yet i would like to call a function after all tests are finished running (in this case test_1 and test_2).

From the documentation looks like the tearDownModule() function should do it, yet this doesnt seem to be called.

Comment: You mean `def teardown_class`??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`tearDownModule`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#setupmodule-and-teardownmodule) is for use on the module scope, not as a method.  Instead, you probably want [`tearDownClass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDownClass):

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        ...
```

Comment: I actually tried this but forgot the decorator! Thank you.

Comment: Can i pass 'self' into this function? Basically i need to access a variable which i'm updating in every tearDown call.

Comment: No, you shouldn't.  It's best to avoid any mutable state between test units.